# speech recognition in java netbeans without using eclipse

Tags: java

I've tried to use sphinx4 in eclipse for speech recognition.But we want to run our code in netbeans...please suggest the code that can run in netbeans without using eclipse.

Comment: Please show what you have tried already.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0f3vvCJWyo

Comment: Stack Overflow is for asking specific programming questions, so we need to see the code you have tried and the error you saw.

Comment: @Blindmail enter your code where u got the error mention it here much be easy to help u